# How do I see the full content of a dimension in a Google Analytics custom report?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I'm using this custom report from the gallery called "Exceptions Report (by Ron Whitman RWDS.co)". Here's a screenshot of how it looks when I try to edit it:

[image]

The problem is, that exception description column is the most important part of this report, but it gets cut off after a few characters and ends in "...". Sometimes the string is very long, and I'd like to be able to make it multiline, too. **How can I see the full Exception Description on my custom report?**

Answer (score -1):

This can't be done. [There is a max length of 150 bytes.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#exception)